# Dissecting a permutation algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I am trying to get my head around how this permutation algorithm works:

```
def perm(n, i):
    if i == len(n) - 1: 
        print n
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            perm(n, i + 1)
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i] # swap back, for the next loop

perm([1, 2, 3], 0)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

**Question**

How is it that the original list is the *first* line printed?

In this example, the length of `n` is 3. Initially, `i` is 0. The code should skip the `if` statement, and then first iteration mutates the list.  How do we get `[1, 2, 3]` as the first line of output?

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger or running it through http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing in the `else`?

Comment: Take a closer look at exactly what it's swapping on the first iteration. Are you sure that iteration *really* changes the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* skip the `if` at the top level.  It drops into the `else` and iterates `j` through the list.  The first iteration has i == j == 0, so the swap does nothing, and you recur with ([1, 2, 3], 1).

This process repeats for the that instance, having i == j == 1.  That recurs with ([1, 2, 3], 2)  *That* instance is the one that print `[1, 2, 3]` as the first line of output.

Does that clear it up?

If not, learn how to insert useful `print` statements to trace execution.
Perhaps this makes it more clear.

```
indent = ""

def perm(n, i):
    global indent
    indent += "  "
    print indent, "ENTER", n, i

    if i == len(n) - 1: 
        print n
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            print indent, "RECUR", i, j
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            perm(n, i + 1)
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i] # swap back, for the next loop

    indent = indent[2:]

perm([1, 2, 3], 0)
```

Output:

```
   ENTER [1, 2, 3] 0
   RECUR 0 0
     ENTER [1, 2, 3] 1
     RECUR 1 1
       ENTER [1, 2, 3] 2
[1, 2, 3]
     RECUR 1 2
       ENTER [1, 3, 2] 2
[1, 3, 2]
   RECUR 0 1
     ENTER [2, 1, 3] 1
     RECUR 1 1
       ENTER [2, 1, 3] 2
[2, 1, 3]
     RECUR 1 2
       ENTER [2, 3, 1] 2
[2, 3, 1]
   RECUR 0 2
     ENTER [3, 2, 1] 1
     RECUR 1 1
       ENTER [3, 2, 1] 2
[3, 2, 1]
     RECUR 1 2
       ENTER [3, 1, 2] 2
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: algorithms are amazing

Comment: I like this indent approach to debugging a recursive function, will have to add that to my bag of tricks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I know that there's an indentation package somewhere that can do this and more, but I keep losing the reference.  I'm not even sure it's Python; might be C++ or Java.  In any case, I've been doing this "pretty-print" since I got into advanced programming back in the days before object-oriented languages matured.